# Request LDAP for a user with the groups he is member of

Tags: java, spring, ldap

I'm discovering LDAP with Java.
I follow this guide to implement a solution to request the LDAP: https://docs.spring.io/spring-ldap/docs/current/reference/

I have been able to query user by login with the following code:

```java
@Entry(objectClasses = { "user" })
public final class Person {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name = "sAMAccountName")
    String login;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    String name;

    ...
}
```

```java
final LdapTemplate ldapTemplate;

...

public Person consultPerson(final String login) {
    final LdapQuery findByLoginQuery = query() //
            .where("sAMAccountName") //
            .is(login);

    return ldapTemplate.findOne(findByLoginQuery, Person.class);
}
```

Now, I want to get the list of group the user is member of.

The following adjusment works but I would prefer to have a list of `Group` instead of a list of `String`.

```java
@Entry(objectClasses = { "user" })
public final class Person {

    @Id
    private Name dn;

    @Attribute(name = "sAMAccountName")
    String login;

    @Attribute(name = "cn")
    String name;

    @Attribute(name = "memberOf")
    Set<String> groups;

    ...
}
```

Unfortunately, I'm not able to do so.

Anybody knows if it's possible ?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

In order to retrieve an operational attribute, you have to require it explicitely, or request all of them using the special attribute '+'.

Click [here](http://directory.apache.org/apacheds/advanced-ug/8-operational-attributes.html)

So in your case the search query would look like:

```
 final LdapQuery findByLoginQuery = query().attributes("sAMAccountName","cn","memberOf")
        .where("sAMAccountName").is(login);
```

Or perhaps:

```
final LdapQuery findByLoginQuery = query().attributes("*","+")
        .where("sAMAccountName").is(login);
```

Where "*" is for all user attributes and "+" is for all operational attributes indicated in your model.